# right-continuous at $0$ implies continuous for semi-group

Tags: semigroup-of-operators, transition-matrix

I'm reading the book "Markov Chains : Gibbs Fields, Monte Carlo Simulation, and Queues" written by Pierre Brémaud In p.333 the author define transition semigroup as this :

Let $(P_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}} \in ([0, 1]^{\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{R}_{+}}$ such that

1. $P_{0}(i, j) = \delta_{i, j}$ for every $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\delta_{i, j}$ is the kronecker symbol.
2. $P_{s+t} = P_{s}P_{t}$ for every $s, t \in \mathbb{N}$ (where $P_{s}P_{t}$ is the matrix multiplication)
3. For every $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, i \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}P_{t}(i, j) = 1$.

Then it's said that if (right-continuous at 0) : $\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} P_{t}(i, j) = \delta_{i, j}$ for every $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$, we have (continuous on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$) : $\lim_{h \to 0} P_{t+h}(i, j) = P_{t}(i, j)$ for every $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, i,j \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can we prove this statement ? The right-continuity for every $t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is clear for me, but I'm blocked by left-continuity.

Comment: Prove from right continuity that for $h > 0$ sufficiently small, $P_h$ is invertible, and that $P_h^{-1} \to \delta$ as $h \to 0+$ as well. Effectively $P_h^{-1} = P_{-h}$ and $P$ is also left-continuous at $0$.

Comment: But the matrix is $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, how can we deduce $P_{h}$ is invertible for $h$ sufficiently small ?

Comment: That the matrices are infinite dimensional introduces all sorts of complications. For instance, if there is an $i'$ such that $\forall j, P_t(i',j) =\frac 1{\sqrt j}$ and a $j'$ such that $\forall i, P_s(i,j') = \frac 1{\sqrt i}$, how would you even define $P_tP_s$? Apparently, there is more to the definition than you've included - restrictions on the allowable "matrices". Without knowing more about space in question, I cannot truly answer your question. But usually the set of degenerate matrices is closed, So any invertible matrix , such as $\delta$, will have an invertible neighborhood.